# Is CouchbaseQueue by default thread safe?

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-java-api

Is CouchbaseQueue API in http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.5.5/com/couchbase/client/java/datastructures/collections/CouchbaseQueue.html 1 thread safe? Or can i achieve the similar behavior by Bucket.getAsync().queuePop()?
I want to access this async behavior from multiple JVM and JVM’s don’t know about each other. I do not want to go with Kafka path at this moment. Can anyone give some light as what will be the best way to achieve async queue behavior or refer me to appropriate section?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, according to the documentation on [Couchbase](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/java/datastructures.html).

> Instead of maintaining in-memory storage, these implementations are backed by JSON documents stored in Couchbase Server. The implementations are thread-safe and suitable for concurrent use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @theMayer.

Comment: Just attaching one more reference here. https://forums.couchbase.com/t/couchbase-queue-by-default-thread-safe/17919